# Extract same column name from multiple data frames in Python

Tags: python, pandas, loops

this is my problem in `python` , I have for now this 5 data frames, each df has the same rows(genes) like 37000, but different number of columns(person), that I want is extract the same columns from each dataframes and put together in a new dataframe from each person.

This is the first data frame(zcwholeblood)

```
    985191          984946          985178          985243  ....
0   -0.333855799    -0.384420271    -0.160796838    -0.048264971    
1   -0.263987736    -0.390621888    1.810548362     -0.145211202    
2   -0.804232112    -1.034259456    0.709356481     1.159014699
3   -1.020565696    -0.951216899    0.746887476     0.491633943 
4   -0.843270991    -0.84398453     0.066100731     -0.186970913    
5   -1.068984477    -0.918156528    0.177400838     0.738998791 
.
```

All the dataframes has the same structure but can or not have the same columns and has different values. This is the code that I did to make a dataframe from the pacient with column name "985191".

```
lp = [zcwholeblood, zcmuscleskeletal, zcskinsun, zclung, zcadiposesubcuta]
L = []
for df in lp:
    L.append((df.loc[:,("985191")]))
pd.DataFrame(L)
```

but it's show me this error

> KeyError: 'the label [985191] is not in the [columns]'

what I don't why and I've changed a little to

```
lp = [zcwholeblood, zcmuscleskeletal, zcskinsun, zclung, zcadiposesubcuta]
L = []
for df.filter in lp:
    L.append((df.loc[:,("985191")]))
pd.DataFrame(L)
```

but shows me this, 5 rows( I guess is for the 5 data frames, but all the rows have the value from the first data frame (zcwholeblood)

```
0       1           2           3           4        ...
985191  -0.333856   -0.263988   -0.804232   -1.020566...        
985191  -0.333856   -0.263988   -0.804232   -1.020566...        
985191  -0.333856   -0.263988   -0.804232   -1.020566...        
985191  -0.333856   -0.263988   -0.804232   -1.020566...        
985191  -0.333856   -0.263988   -0.804232   -1.020566...        
5 rows × 37605 columns
```

I really appreciate if you can help me, cause this is a project that I have from school

Comment: Are you sure your dataframe has a column with the name "985191"? (Remember that "985191" is not the same as 985191.)

Comment: @DyZ Yes, I'm sure, I'm going to edit the post and put one of the data frames

Comment: Does `"985191" in df` evaluate to `True`?

Comment: yes it's evaluate `True`

Comment: For each of the five dataframes? By the way, you should use not `df.loc[:,("985191")]` but `df["985191"]`.

Comment: Also check if there are any spaces in the column name "985191" either before or after the digits (e.g., "   985191").